# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

Tags: java, android, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I am using Eclipse with Android SDK.

I want to access to SQL Server 2008.

When I used String ...

```
classforname= "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
```

I used JDK 1.7 and configured build pbath to rt.jar.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you don't wana use jdbc on android, belive me, it is a bad idea ... proper way is to use REST service and HTTP protocol(prefer JSON over XML/SOAP as transport)

Comment: anyway, you can waste your time and try http://jtds.sourceforge.net/ but it will be better for your sanity to do some research on REST solution

Answer (score 8):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are attempting to use ODBC on Android. ODBC is a Windows technology, and Android is not Windows. There is no `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` on Android.

You will need to find some other solution for your database access. Selvin's suggestion of a REST Web service is the typical approach.